# How to add scoped repository values in topology manager

Tags: dxa, topology-manager, dxa-2.0

I have multiple websites under a topology manager. For some of the websites I have scoped repository values and for some I don't have the values. How should I add the scoped repository values for the websites for which I don't have the values?

Answer (score 2):

To Applying Site Type Keys (ScopedRepositoryKeys) to DXA Web Applications  in Topology manager

**Syntax:**

```
 Add-TtmSiteTypeKey -CdTopologyId <String> -WebApplicationIds <List`1[String]> [-Key] <String> [-TtmServiceUrl <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Examples:**

```
--------------------------  Example 1  --------------------------

Add-TtmSiteTypeKey -WebApplicationIds Website1_RootWebApp -CdTopologyId DxaStagingLive -Key Microsite

Adds the key 'Microsite' to the chain in between Web Application 'Website1_RootWebApp' and Cd Topology 'DxaStagingLive'

--------------------------  Example 2  --------------------------

Add-TtmSiteTypeKey -WebApplicationIds Website1_RootWebApp, Website2_RootWebApp -CdTopologyId DxaStagingLive -Key Microsite

Adds the key 'Microsite' to the chain in between Web Application 'Website1_RootWebApp' and Cd Topology 'DxaStagingLive' and also the chain between 'Website2_RootWebApp' and Cd Topology 'DxaStagingLive'
```

To get the WebApplicationIds by **Get-TtmWebApplication** cmdlets command

To get the CdTopologyId by **Get-TtmCdTopology** cmdlets command

I hope it helps.